# Use Excel VBA to Search One cell for one value and on the same line another cell for another value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on what will be a massive VBA script once done but I am having an issue when it gets to where I need the VBA script check for this logic:

```
If Cell AC2 = "PastDue" And Cell W2 <> "Risk Accepted" on Sheet1 Then Copy row to Sheet2.
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub PastDue()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Job Updating"

Dim lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim r As long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet1
Dim ws2 As Worksheet2

Application.ScreenUpdating= False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
N = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "AC").End(x1Up).Row 'Used to search column AC
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(x1Up).Row 'This errors out when ran and was a line I added in to check the second column
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End.x1Up).Row

    For r = 2 To lr
        If ws1.Range("AC" & r).Value = "PastDue" Then
            If ws1.Range ("W" & r).Value <> "Risk Accepted" Then 'I added this to search for the second piece of the logic
                ws1.Rows(r).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & N + 1)
            N = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        End If
   Next r
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is a slightly modified code from one that does work when only looking for a single value in one column

Comment: And that issue is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code out on some mock data, and it seemed to work aside from a handful of odd mistakes. I'm not sure if these mistakes are oversights when copying code to StackOveflow, or if they actually exist in your VBA. I'm not sure how your code worked when searching for only a single value, if this is indeed your code.

1. You `Dim` your worksheets as `Worksheet1` and `Worksheet2`. These are not class names. Change the lines to read: `Dim ws1 as Worksheet` and `Dim ws2 as Worksheet`.
2. The argument that you are passing to the `End` function is `x1up` (note, you are using the number one instead of the letter `l`.

When I changed these two items, the code seemed to work. I stress the word "seem" because I'm not sure what your errors were. You'll need to expound.

The code I ultimately used:

```
Sub PastDue()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Job Updating"

Dim lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
N = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row 'Used to search column AC
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row 'This errors out when ran and was a line I added in to check the second column
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 2 To lr
        If ws1.Range("AC" & r).Value = "PastDue" Then
            If ws1.Range("W" & r).Value <> "Risk Accepted" Then  'I added this to search for the second piece of the logic
                ws1.Rows(r).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & N + 1)
            N = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        End If
   Next r
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: haha when looking through the original code I did do a double-take at the `x1up` but I thought it was just me!

Comment: FWIW - another issue is that the first `lr =` statement isn't needed.  (Or, it may be needed, but isn't useful as currently written because `lr` is immediately overwritten on the next line.)  And `lr2` isn't used after it is assigned a value - I suspect it and `N` are meant to be one variable.

Comment: So I took the code and yes I typo-ed the 1 instead of l :P.  Now it does run without any error but no results are pasted on worksheet 2.  What can I do to:

1.  Cleanup the LR1 and LR2 since I need to look in Column AC for value = "PastDue" and then column W for value <> "RiskAccepted".

Comment: Now it does run without any error but no results are pasted on worksheet 2.  What can I do to:
1.  Cleanup the LR1 and LR2 since I need to look in Column AC for value = "PastDue" and then column W for value <> "RiskAccepted".
2.  When I used someone elses code, it had the "N = 1. Which from looking at the code it was used to to place the first pasted row on Sheet 2 into row B.  I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing this but since it worked I figured I would just run with it.  
I do have a sheet with the data if someone wants it.

Comment: I was able to fix the past issue as the variable changed in format from and old export to the new export.  So looking at how I have it looking at 2 variables, what if I wanted to have it look at 3 variables now?  
Do I need to add another DIM?

Comment: @SMonik Within your for loop, just add another nested if statement. You don't need a variable to hold that.